# Android permissions dialog not being show when trying to get READ_PHONE_STATE permissions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

I am trying to use READ_PHONE_STATE permissions and as such (they are considered dangerous permissions) I have to check if already granted and then ask for permission if not granted.   My check (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission) is return false so I run ActivityCompat.requestPermissions.  The dialog that is supposed to show is not appearing.

I am targeting API 28, so I have tried to add READ_CALL_LOG permissions, also considered dangerous, but those too are not being granted.

```
            var selfPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)

            if (selfPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                val perms = arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, perms,
                    Constants.PERMISSION_READ_CALL_LOG_REQUEST)
                selfPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)
            }

            if (selfPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                return
            }

            selfPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)

            if (selfPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                val perms = arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, perms,
                    Constants.PERMISSION_READ_PHONE_REQUEST)
                selfPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
            }

            if (selfPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                return
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem and in my case it was due to the thread I was running my `requestPermission` call on, which **was not UI thread** (Java executor).

So to fix this you should just make sure you're on the main thread as so (Java version):

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, perms,
                Constants.PERMISSION_READ_CALL_LOG_REQUEST);
    }
});
```